# Does this patent mean I cannot build a better system?

Tags: patent-infringement, software

Is it safe to assume that due to this patent below - NO other system, web-based or other, can be put into place to compete?  Can I not build my own MIS system?

In reference to the patent: [US20110123079](https://www.google.com/patents/US20110123079)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to assume that due to this patent below - NO other system, web-based or other, can be put into place to compete? Can I not build my own MIS system?

That patent is a "pre-Alice patent". IANAL, but it appears somewhat unlikely to me that, for example, Claim 1 in that patent is significantly more than an abstract idea. You can also try to find prior art that could be used to invalidate the patent in the event of being sued for infringing it. You can also hire a lawyer to look at several of possible reasons for why the patent might be invalid and get an "opinion of counsel" stating that the patent is likely invalid. Doing so won't invalidate the patent, but it will make it harder to find you at fault for *willfull* infringement. Basically, having the opinion lowers your damages if you happen get sued and lose the case.

So, you have basically three options.

Option one is to give up.

Option two is to just go ahead and build your own MIS that might infringe, and wait to be sued. Statistically speaking, your MIS system business is much more likely to fail as a business than to be successful enough to be worth suing. The good part is that once you're worth suing, you probably also have enough cash flow to lawyer up. Many patents are found invalid or not infringed in litigation. It's also not the end of the world if you end up having to pay a reasonable royalty.

Option three is to design a MIS system different enough that it doesn't infringe (and possibly file your own patents on it, if you have an invention that is not abstract in the post-Alice world).

All of the above assumes you want to start a business. If you just want to make a MIS system for the heck of it and release it as FOSS, then I guess that obviously limits your options in terms of getting appropriate legal advice, etc.